# Power bi 100% Stacked bar from Excel data

Tags: python, powerbi, stacked-bar-chart

I can plot a 100% stacked bar from Excel. is it possible to achieve the same with Power Bi ?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
        [40 , 30 , 20 , 10],
        [50 , 30 , 60 , 10],
        [10 , 40 , 20 , 80]
        
]

columns = ["A","B","C","D" ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data , columns=columns , index = ["Empty" , "Wrong" , "Correct"] )

data2 = df.T
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your dataframe is a pivot table, I think you need to unpivot it (NOTA: which means recovering your raw data, so if toi have raw data, it Can be more efficient to import it in powerbi and if needed to tranform the data on power Query):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
        [40 , 30 , 20 , 10],
        [50 , 30 , 60 , 10],
        [10 , 40 , 20 , 80]
        
]

columns = ["A","B","C","D" ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data , columns=columns)
df[result] = ["Empty" , "Wrong" , "Correct"]
df_unpivot = pd.melt(df, id_vars='result', value_vars=["A","B","C","D" ] )
```